# Does Bigquery instance in java api refresh it's Oauth 2.0 authorization automatically after building it with a credential that has a refresh token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-bigquery

Good day,

I was recently testing Oauth2.0 Installed application authentication for bigquery through java api.
I used 
[this command line sample](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/shared/shared-sample-cmdline/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/?repo=samples#samples%2Fshared%2Fcmdline%2Foauth2)
 as a source since i want to make it for the users eaiser to give access (it would be ugly to ask them to copy the code)

If i use SetAccessType(Offline) in GoogleAuthorizationCodeflow it says, that it automatically refreshes the access token for me.

In related I'd like to ask, if i authorize a com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery instance with 
com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Builder.Builder(HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, HttpRequestInitializer httpRequestInitializer)
using
credentials that have a refresh token, do i have to reauthorize it or it will update the credentials inside itself?

If it does not give me a valid connection to bigquery after one hour (token expiration time)
then which is the best method to reauthorize the client?

Shall i use credentials.RefreshToken() and then just Build another bigquery instance whith the new access token, or there is a better way?

(I may also want to change the credentials Refreshlistener, but the problem is that if i instantinate the credential with GoogleAuthorizationCodeflow.createAndStoreCredential(response, Clientid) after that i cannot get the Refreshlistener. How can i get it, so i may use that class to automatically reauthorize my Bigquery Client  < maybe this is the better way is it?)

Where does the codeflow store the refreshed access token (if it refreshes it automatically)?
If i declared it like this:

```
new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
              transport, jsonFactory, clientSecrets, scopes).setAccessType("offline")
              .setApprovalPrompt("auto").setCredentialStore(new MemoryCredentialStore()).build();
```

Will it store my refreshed access token always in the MemoryCredentialStore? 
So if i use .getCredentialStore().load(userId, credential) it will load the refreshed access token from the memorystore?

Is there a way to increase or decrease the time while an access token is valid? Since for testing purposes i really want to do so.

p.s: I was also looking into this source code of google-api-java-client
and google-oauth-java-client but i still couldn't find the sollution.

Most importantly I was looking into: [class Credential](http://code.google.com/p/google-oauth-java-client/source/browse/google-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/Credential.java?r=3797dd06637996cb2bd231dd9c19925d80295de3) at code: 
public void intercept(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {
    lock.lock();...
but I couldnt figure it out actually when this method is called and I eventually got lost in the problem.

Looking forward to your answer:
Attila

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of questions here. You will want to use the GoogleCredential class to gain a new access token from an existing refresh token, that you well need to store (using whatever method you want, such as MemoryCredentialStore).

The access token only lasts for an hour and there is not way to change this.

Here is an example using the installed flow:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;


class BigQueryInstalledAuthDemo {

  // Change this to your current project ID
  private static final String PROJECT_NUMBER = "XXXXXXXXXX";

  // Load Client ID/secret from client_secrets.json file.
  private static final String CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = "client_secrets.json";
  static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = loadClientSecrets();

  private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

  // Objects for handling HTTP transport and JSON formatting of API calls
  private static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  private static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;

  // BigQuery Client
  static Bigquery bigquery;


  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Attempt to Load existing Refresh Token
    String storedRefreshToken = loadRefreshToken();

    // Check to see if the an existing refresh token was loaded.
    // If so, create a credential and call refreshToken() to get a new
    // access token.
    if (storedRefreshToken != null) {

      // Request a new Access token using the refresh token.
      GoogleCredential credential = createCredentialWithRefreshToken(
          HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new TokenResponse().setRefreshToken(storedRefreshToken));
      credential.refreshToken();

      bigquery = buildService(credential);

    // If there is no refresh token (or token.properties file), start the OAuth
    // authorization flow.
    } else {
      String authorizeUrl = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(
          clientSecrets,
          REDIRECT_URI,
          Collections.singleton(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY)).setState("").build();

      System.out.println("Paste this URL into a web browser to authorize BigQuery Access:\n" + authorizeUrl);

      System.out.println("... and type the code you received here: ");
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String authorizationCode = in.readLine();

      // Exchange the auth code for an access token and refesh token
      Credential credential = exchangeCode(authorizationCode);

      // Store the refresh token for future use.
      storeRefreshToken(credential.getRefreshToken());

      bigquery = buildService(credential);
    }

    // Make API calls using your client.
    listDatasets(bigquery, PROJECT_NUMBER);

  }


  /**
   *  Builds an authorized BigQuery API client.
   */
  private static Bigquery buildService(Credential credential) {
    return new Bigquery.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential).build();
  }


  /**
   * Build an authorization flow and store it as a static class attribute.
   */
  static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow getFlow() {
    if (flow == null) {
      flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT,
          JSON_FACTORY,
          clientSecrets,
          Collections.singleton(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY))
      .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
    }
    return flow;
  }


  /**
   * Exchange the authorization code for OAuth 2.0 credentials.
   */
  static Credential exchangeCode(String authorizationCode) throws IOException  {
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = getFlow();
    GoogleTokenResponse response =
        flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
    return flow.createAndStoreCredential(response, null);
  }


  /**
   * No need to go through OAuth dance, get an access token using the
   * existing refresh token.
   */
  public static GoogleCredential createCredentialWithRefreshToken(HttpTransport transport,
      JsonFactory jsonFactory, TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
    return new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(transport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setClientSecrets(clientSecrets)
        .build()
        .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
  }


  /**
   *  Helper to load client ID/Secret from file.
   */
  private static GoogleClientSecrets loadClientSecrets() {
    try {
      GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
          GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(),
              BigQueryInstalledAuthDemo.class.getResourceAsStream(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION));
      return clientSecrets;
    } catch (Exception e)  {
      System.out.println("Could not load clientsecrets.json");
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return clientSecrets;
  }


  /**
   *  Helper to store a new refresh token in token.properties file.
   */
  private static void storeRefreshToken(String refresh_token) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("refreshtoken", refresh_token);
    System.out.println(properties.get("refreshtoken"));
    try {
      properties.store(new FileOutputStream("token.properties"), null);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }


  /**
   *  Helper to load refresh token from the token.properties file.
   */
  private static String loadRefreshToken(){
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    try {
      properties.load(new FileInputStream("token.properties"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return (String) properties.get("refreshtoken");
  }


  /**
   *
   * List available Datasets.
   */
  public static void listDatasets(Bigquery bigquery, String projectId)
      throws IOException {
    Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list(projectId);
    DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
    if (datasetList.getDatasets() != null) {
      List<DatasetList.Datasets> datasets = datasetList.getDatasets();
      System.out.println("Available datasets\n----------------");
      for (com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList.Datasets dataset : datasets) {
        System.out.format("%s\n", dataset.getDatasetReference().getDatasetId());
      }
    }
  }

}
```

An alternative to authorization via storing and using a refresh token to acquire a new access token in your installed application is to use a [server to server service account authorization](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) flow. In this case, your application will need to be able to securely store and use a unique private key. Here is an example of this type of flow using the Google Java API Client:

```
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;

public class JavaCommandLineServiceAccounts {

  private static final String SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery";
  private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  private static Bigquery bigquery;

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
    GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(TRANSPORT)
        .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
        .setServiceAccountId("XXXXXXX@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
        .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPE)
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("my_file.p12"))
        .build();

    bigquery = new Bigquery.Builder(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName("BigQuery-Service-Accounts/0.1")
        .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();

    Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list("publicdata");
    DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
    System.out.format("%s\n", datasetList.toPrettyString());
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for posting the code for server to server authentication, we've already been looking into that but, that sollution was not what we wanted to use since it uses a file for authentication and since its a service account there is no way to set priviliges depending on datasets.

Comment: About the other authorization sample, that is what we exactly used, not really in the same way, but we have used an installed application id and clientsecret to get credentials with authorizationflow (setaccestype(offline)) and we've built the bigquery instance with the credentials involving refresh and access token. My question was more likely about if we shall manually always rebuild the connection to bigquery with new access token got by credentials.refreshToken() or the bigquery api does it by itself?

Comment: Luckily after we have made a 2 hour Junit test to test it out and since it worked just fine without any manual interactions with the credentials or the built bigquery connection i guess the answer is that it does use the refresh token automatically to refresh the connection to bigquery. Thank you very much for really trying to help me out though. Is there a way to get in contact with bigquery support live, like chat or voice chat? There are lots of small questions throughout our developement project which if answered in time we could make an elegant cutoff in developement time. Thank you again